# asp.net databind expression not evaluating

Tags: asp.net, inline-code

The following code:

aspx file:

```
<div id="challengedIndependence" class="collegeAccentBlock grid_8 push_1" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style='display:<%# testMethod %>' >
```

associated aspx.cs file:

```
  public string testMethod()
    {
        return "none;";
    }
```

rendered html file:

```
<div id="challengedIndependence" class="collegeAccentBlock grid_8 push_1" style="display:&lt;%# testMethod %&gt;">
</div>
```

I am expecting the result to rendder as ...style:"display:none;"... what am I doing wrong.

Not sure if this should be in the same question:  I am doing this because I have multiple lines of code to determine whether this div should be displayed.   If there is another way of doing this and an explanation as to why it is better I would also accept that answer.

Reference: [Inline expressions referenced on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)

Comment: Where are you performing the data binding?

Comment: Does it work with property instead of a method?

Comment: After Oded's comment I changed the code to use the display expression directive `<%= %>` which did not work and I m unsure why.  The data binding occurs as file.aspx.cs for file.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use an inline expression here, it needs to be the entire content of that attribute, like this:

```
<div id="challengedIndependence" class="collegeAccentBlock grid_8 push_1" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style='<%# testMethod() %>' >
```

and then return the entire string you want there. It's just rendering it as part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Dictate an UI style by code behind looks not right, but anyway try to return whole style string like `return "display:none"` and bind to style attribute